# Publishing Actions on google without Dialogflow

Tags: actions-on-google

I am building a Google Assistant action without using Dialogflow instead using our own NLG / NLU , i am using **gactions** cli to upload my action file, all works fine , while i am able to test in simulator as well on my phone,

I am unable to submit for Alpha / Beta testing, all i see is those buttons disabled and its saying i do not have any action (as i am not using dialogflow).

How can i submit action for Alpha/Beta testing?
[image: Disabled Submit button]

[image: Not recognising the actions uploaded via action package]

Comment: it seems something was wrong with that particular project, i created a new one and it seems to be working fine now.  One more things i noticed is that you have to do gactions update --project <projectname> --action_package <actionpackage file> and then your actions start showing in console

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't defined any actions in the action package (the file you upload using the `gactions` tool). Unfortunately "action" has several meanings here. One is the app itself, another is the things it can do via 'intents'.

Try adding the main intent to your action package:

```
{
    "actions": [
        {
            "description": "Default Welcome Intent",
            "name": "MAIN",
            "fulfillment": {
                "conversationName": "HelloWorld"
            },
            "intent": {
                "name": "actions.intent.MAIN",
                "trigger": {
                "queryPatterns": [
                    "Open hello world"
                ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The `conversationName` field must be the same as the one you define under `conversations` in the same file.

```
"conversations": {
    "HelloWorld": {
        "name": "HelloWorld",
        "url": "https://myapp.example.com",
        "fulfillmentApiVersion": 2,
    }
}
```

Comment: i have uploaded the action with MAIN and TEXT intent but they do not show in console, although i am able to test it via simulator and even on my phone

Comment: I'm confused. You say you have uploaded the action package and they do not show up in the console, then in another comment to the question, you say you upload it and it does work. Was the original project somehow broken?

Comment: initially i uploaded the file via gactions  "test" flag , and the project was not showing my intents (from action.json) , then i created a new project and ran gactions with "test" flag and then with "update" flag and intents started showing in google's action console, its still not working in previous project but somehow works in newer ones